# Writing a script

Tags: shell, autocad

AutoCAD can convert PDF to DWG but only one page at a time. I'm trying to write a script to automate it and let it batch process it. I don't have much experience in shell though and not sure how to do that. Can someone please help me?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried googling here and there but I haven't learnt much out of it. I never wrote any scripts before.

Comment: I got passed the part for opening the application but that's about it. I have no idea what to do now. I am using Notepad on windows

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to accomplish this from a script file.

Easiest solution is to export the separate PDF sheets and combine them by hand using Acrobat or another PDF application.

Second option is to look into a 3rd party library like itextsharp to combine the sheets for you.